# About the self-adjoint extension of one linear differential operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I`m trying to solve some problems and I need your help.

Consider $$A: \;\;-\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}: C[0,\pi] \to C[0,\pi];\;\;\; y(0)=y(\pi)=0$$.

It is unbounded, closed and symmetric, but not self-adjoint. The question is how can I find conditions of existence of self-adjoint extension; what is the simpiest way to solve it? Is it necessary to find deficiency indices (the necessary and sufficient condition is an equality of deficiency indices)
or this problem has a simple decision? And what literature would you advice?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you mean $C^2[0,\pi]\to C[0,\pi]$?

Comment: $$D(A) = C^2 [0,\pi]$$

Comment: @MariamFatima: Well, $C[0,\pi]$ is not a Hilbert space so it doesn't make sense to talk about symmetric and self-adjoint operators in this context.

Comment: @levap True! Thanks for this important note! And if we consider $L_2 [0,\pi]...$

Comment: $A : C^2[0,1] \subset L^2[0,1] \rightarrow L^2[0,1]$ is essentially selfadjoint.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, your comment is a bit ambiguous, since it's not quite true, as you yourself probably are aware, that the map from $C^2$ to $L^2$ is essentially self-adjoint, without the boundary conditions that make it really a question on the circle. That is, with either Dirichlet or vonNeumann boundary conditions, there are complications at the endpoints... which the questioner might need to be made aware of in greater detail.

Comment: @paulgarrett : The definition of $A$ includes the endpoint conditions. I didn't bother to restate them. But I did restate the spaces for $A$ because that part of the definition has to be changed in order to discuss selfadjointness.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts, ok, fine, good, and/but I hope the questioner does notice these critical details. Hopefully our comments here are helpful.

Comment: @paulgarrett : Yes, the clarification is good so there is no ambiguity, especially because of the suggestion in the post that the $A$ with Dirichlet conditions may have multiple selfadjoint extensions, which is does not. The operator with $y(0)=y(\pi)=y'(0)=y'(\pi)$ of course does have multiple selfadjoint extensions.

Comment: @paulgarrett
@DisintegratingByParts
Thank you for this discussion. I see, I need more practise and understanding.
At the exam (that I've already passed) the examinator gave me a task with this operator, but did not specify the space, the domain , without any boundary conditions. I had to research the (un)boundness, symmetry, self-adjointness, the existence of self-adjoint extensions and conditions (?) on eigenfunctions .
Now I am very curious how to formulate the problem correctly and interesting. 
So, with conditions $y(0)=y(\pi)=y'(0)=y`(\pi)$ the problem become more interesting...